# Where to put unverified users?

Tags: android, ios, mongodb, web, backend

I am building an APP that will allow users to create an account. After registration, a verification email will be sent to their email address containing a 6 digit code that they will have to input in order to verify their account.

The question is, prior to their account being verified, where do I put this document in my database? Do I put it in a separate collection or do I put it in the regular users collection with a flag to indicate that this use is not verified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can certainly work either way.

I expect keeping them in the same collection would be the most common approach.  However if you expect to have a huge number of unverified users or may grow your verification approach to require more complex data you may benefit from using different collections.

I think the best general advice is to keep it simple until you have a clear reason to add complexity.  Then you can design for that known shortcoming in your simple solution.  In this case having a single user collection would be the simpler approach, as you avoid having to move verified users to a new collection.